# Elastic Search perform calculation on one document

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to perform a calculation on a field of a specific document. As an example, I need to sum 50 to a price. I have tried the following options:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/ex1/ex2/WPatZHgBEd7rI-6ZwNFC/_update?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"doc": {"price": +50}}'
```

In this case it sets the price as 50. and if I try this:

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/ex1/ex2/WPatZHgBEd7rI-6ZwNFC/_update?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"doc": {"price": "price"+50}}'
```

it gives the following error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "json_parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4c7cecda; line: 1, column: 29]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "json_parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Unexpected character ('-' (code 45)): was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@4c7cecda; line: 1, column: 29]"
  },
  "status" : 500
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a script to [increment a doc's attribute](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html#docs-update-api-query-params):

```json
POST localhost:9200/ex1/ex2/WPatZHgBEd7rI-6ZwNFC/_update?pretty
{
  "script": {
    "source": "ctx._source.price += params.increment_by",
    "params": {
      "increment_by": 50
    }
  }
}
```

With cURL:

```sh
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/localhost:9200/ex1/ex2/WPatZHgBEd7rI-6ZwNFC/_update?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{  "script": {    "source": "ctx._source.price += params.increment_by",    "params": {      "increment_by": 50    }  }}'
```